# List of Dictionaries, Get Dictionary name, I am unable to show the name of the Dictionary when iterating the List of Dictionaries

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary

In a List with Dictionaries, I am unable to show the name of the Dictionary.
How can I get that done?
In For Each Item, Item already gets the String, String.
See image, it says:
The value of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String) cannot be converted to String.

How?

```
Dim ListOfDictionaries = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) ' From { Dictionary1, Dictionary2 }

Dim Dictionary1 As New Dictionary( Of String, String)
Dim Dictionary2 As New Dictionary( Of String, String)
Dim Dictionary3 As New Dictionary( Of String, String)

ListOfDictionaries.Add(Dictionary1)
ListOfDictionaries.Add(Dictionary2)
ListOfDictionaries.Add(Dictionary3)

Logger.Info(ListOfDictionaries.Count)

If Not ListOfDictionaries.Contains(Dictionary3) Then
    ListOfDictionaries.Add(Dictionary3)
End If

Dictionary1.Add("A", "Letter")
Dictionary1.Add("B", "Letter")
Dictionary1.Add("C", "Letter")

Dictionary2.Add("A", "Letter")
Dictionary2.Add("B", "Letter")
Dictionary2.Add("C", "Letter")

Dictionary3.Add("A", "Letter")
Dictionary3.Add("B", "Letter")
Dictionary3.Add("C", "Letter")

Logger.Info(ListOfDictionaries.Count)
For Each item In ListOfDictionaries
        
    Logger.Info(Item)
    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In item
    
        Logger.Info(pair.Key,pair.Value)
    
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Instead of `List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))` you could have `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))`. Then you can do `dictionaryOfDictionaries.Add("Dictionary1", dictionary1)`. (It is conventional to use lower case for the first character of a variable.)

Comment: That's also a very good idea.

Comment: That is what I really needed. Can you show me how I can iterate over the dictionaryOfDictionaries and then the inner-loop?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as you have already: I've added an answer that shows how.

Comment: @CheckMaster - Please don't get confused with the concept that a because variable has a name then the thing that the variable holds has the same name. Dictionaries ***do not have names***. The variable that refers to the dictionary ***has a name***.

Comment: @CheckMaster - Think of it like this. `Dim x = 42 : Dim y = x` - now what "name" does `42` have? `x` or `y`? It doesn't have a name. `x` is the name of the variable that holds `42` and so is `y`. Your three `Dictionary(Of String, String)` instances ***do not have a name***.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))` you could have `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))`. Then you can do `dictionaryOfDictionaries.Add("Dictionary1", dictionary1)`, like this:

```
Dim allDictionaries = New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))

Dim dictionary1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim dictionary2 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim dictionary3 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

allDictionaries.Add("Dictionary1", dictionary1)
allDictionaries.Add("Dictionary2", dictionary2)
allDictionaries.Add("Dictionary3", dictionary3)

Logger.Info(allDictionaries.Count)

If Not allDictionaries.ContainsKey("Dictionary3") Then
    allDictionaries.Add("Dictionary3", dictionary3)
End If

dictionary1.Add("A", "Letter")
dictionary1.Add("B", "Letter")
dictionary1.Add("C", "Letter")

dictionary2.Add("A", "Letter")
dictionary2.Add("B", "Letter")
dictionary2.Add("C", "Letter")

dictionary3.Add("A", "Letter")
dictionary3.Add("B", "Letter")
dictionary3.Add("C", "Letter")

Logger.Info(allDictionaries.Count)

For Each item In allDictionaries
    Logger.Info(item.Key)

    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In item.Value
        Logger.Info(pair.Key, pair.Value)
    Next

Next
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help, very nice and clear!